# QQ-plots between a control distribution and multiple treatment distributions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in the following form:

`df = data.frame(data = rnorm(33), group = rep(1:3, times = 10:12))`

The actual data has many more rows and five total groups, but the structure is the same. I'm interested in visualizing the differences in the data distribution between the control group (1 in this case), and the other groups using qq-plots. I can make the plot I want in the following way:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
qqplot(df$data[df$group == 1], df$data[df$group == 2])
abline(0, 1)
qqplot(df$data[df$group == 1], df$data[df$group == 3])
abline(0, 1)
```

This is just two side-by-side qq-plots where the x-axis distributions is from group 1 and the y-axes are from groups 2 and 3. With cleaning this plot is serviceable, but I'd rather make it with `geom_qq` and `facet_grid` from the `ggplot2` library. The closest I've come to a solution is:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(sample = data)) + 
  geom_qq() +
  facet_grid(~group)
```

However, this uses normal quantiles for the x-axis, and I'd like to use the empirical quantiles from the control group (so that the first panel should be a straight line). There is an option to change the distribution in the `geom_qq` function which seems promising, but I can't seem to define it properly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be less mysterious than I thought. Posting my answer for posterity. Turns out you can just compute the coordinates pretty easily and use `geom_point`. This solution uses `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`.

```
plotSeq = seq(0.001, 0.999, length = 200)

makeQ = function(index, seq = plotSeq){
  quantile(df$data[df$group == index], seq)
}

qqplotData = data.table(controlQ = makeQ(1),
                        `Treatment 1` = makeQ(2),
                        `Treatment 2` = makeQ(3)) %>%
  pivot_longer(2:3, names_to = "Treatment", values_to = "Quantiles")

ggplot(qqplotData, aes(x = controlQ, y = Quantiles)) + 
  geom_step(cex = 2) + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~Treatment, nrow = 2)
```